# One revision per entity

Tags: nhibernate-envers

I am just starting with nhibernate-envers so, please, bear with me.
I am trying to manage a typical situation where I have customer and orders.

I would like to have different revisions for each entity.

I was wondering if it is possible to customize the the environment so that my customers have a progressive revision and my orders have another one, each starting from 1.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain why you need that?

Comment: I guess cause it's easier to understand. Let's say my order has got 8 revisions and a customer 1 but the customer is the last one to be saved. It would have rev. 9. If I want to show this info to a user I would have to figure out where are the others, query the db.

Comment: Ok. AFAIK - the revision number is not intended to be used as a "business value" but is a "technical number" used by Envers. Wrote an answer below.

Comment: FYI, even though Envers query api isn't complete or perfect, it's quite powerful. Dependending on what exactly you want to do, it may be something for you to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The revision number is a global number for your domain model (like a changeset number for a repository in a VCS).